# correctly aggregating model objects and simple view calculation

Tags: django, django-views

if "allotted_pto" (paid time off) is an integer field (expressing number of days) in a UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    ...
    allotted_pto = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

and "total_days" returns an integer from a vacation request model:

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=False, null=False)
    ...
    total_days = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
            return u'%s %s' % (self.employee, self.submit_date)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            fromdate = self.start_date
            todate = self.return_date
            daygenerator = (fromdate + timedelta(x + 1) for x in xrange((todate - fromdate).days))
            self.total_days = sum(1 for day in daygenerator if day.weekday() < 5)
            super(LeaveRequest, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            ...
```

how can I construct a view that gives me the sum of "total_days" from a filter set of records and subtract that sum from the "allotted_pto" in the user profile? The simple view I wrote (see below) produces the number of "total_days" objects (in dictionary form) as opposed to counting the actual days, and the request for "allotted_pto" is apparently incorrectly constructed because it returns nothing at all...

```
#views.py 

def leave_screen(request, id):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=id)
    records = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id)
    agg_pto = LeaveRequest.objects.aggregate(Count('total_days'))
    if profile.allotted_pto: #if the allotted_pto field in UserProfile is not empty
            allotted_pto = profile.allotted_pto
            remaining_pto = allotted_pto - agg_pto
    else:
            remaining_pto = "na"
    return render_to_response("vacation/leave_request.html", {'records': records, 'agg_pto': agg_pto, 'remaining_pto': remaining_pto})
```

---

ok, figured out calculation:

```
def leave_screen(request, id):
    ...
    agg_pto = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id).aggregate(Sum('total_days'))
    agg_pto = agg_pto['total_days__sum']
```

just have to figure out how to pull the allotted_pto integer from the User Profile model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so this wasn't as difficult as I thought. The first challenge was to get an aggregate sum of objects. My first attempt was close but I should have just used "Sum" as opposed to "Count":

```
agg_pto = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id).aggregate(Sum('total_days'))
```

then I just used the python method for extracting the value from a dictionary:

```
agg_pto = agg_pto['total_days__sum']
```

finally:

```
def leave_screen(request, id):
    user = request.user.id
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    records = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id).order_by('-submit_date')
    agg_pto = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(employee=id).aggregate(Sum('total_days'))
    agg_pto = agg_pto['total_days__sum']
    allotted_pto = profile.allotted_pto
    if allotted_pto: #if the allotted_pto field in UserProfile is not empty
            remaining_pto = allotted_pto - agg_pto
    else:
            remaining_pto = "na"
    supervised_records = LeaveRequest.objects.filter(supervisor=id).order_by('-submit_date')
    return render_to_response("vacation/leave_request.html", {'records': records, 'supervised_records': supervised_records, 'agg_pto': agg_pto, 'allotted_pto': allotted_pto, 'remaining_pto': remaining_pto, 'profile': profile })
```

I don't know why it was so hard for me to figure out the syntax for pulling objects from the UserProfile. But I do know that the django-debug-toolbar is very helpful.